# Did not understand meaning of $.variableName = functionName in Titanium Alloy Controller

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I was trying to mimic an activity indicator module in Appcelerator Titanium Alloy.
It works fine but I did not understand the working of 2 lines.

activityIndicator.js

```js
$.hide = hide; // <= What does these two lines
$.show = show; // <= means. How Iam able to access hide and show functions in dashboard.js controller directly?

function hide () {
  $.loadingOverlay.hide();
  $.loadingIndicator.hide();
}

function show () {
  $.loadingOverlay.show();
  $.loadingIndicator.show();
}

(function init(){
     Titanium.API.trace("[activityIndicator] >> [init]");
})();
```

activityIndicator.xml

```html
<Alloy>
  <View id="loadingOverlay" visible="false" zIndex="1">
    <ActivityIndicator id="loadingIndicator"/>
  </View>
</Alloy>
```

I am requiring this file in another view namely dashboard.xml

and in dashboard.js controller I am using $.loadIndicator.show() and $.loadIndicator.hide() function.

dashboard.js

```js
//just the function related to loadIndicator
function serviceFailed(e) {
 
    $.loadIndicator.hide(); //hide function works well.
    
    var errorMessage = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : "Error loading data!",
        color : "red"
    });
    $.listContainer.add(errorMessage);
    alert("Failed:" + e.toString());
}

////just the function related to loadIndicator
function showList() {
    
    $.loadIndicator.show(); //this also works fine.
 
    serviceUtil.doUtilServiceCall(function(resp)    {
        populateList(resp);
        ReceivedData = resp;
        Ti.API.info('Data is set to response received.');
    }, serviceFailed);
}
```

---

If I comment out first two lines in activityIndicator.js

```js
$.hide = hide;
$.show = show;
```

then it shows show loadIndicator.show is not a function. and same for hide function.

What I do not understand is how those two lines are making hide and show function accessible. And what can be possible equivalent code of those two lines.

What is $ referring to in here?

> **After going through other widgets I get the convention that, if you require a widget in View instead of Controller then using $.variable sets it as visible to outside world. Same way as module.exports sets it visible to outside world.**

*Please correct me if I am wrong.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found Answer on Appceleraor's wiki : [creating widgets](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Alloy+Widgets#AlloyWidgets-CreatingWidgets)

All methods in the widget controller are private unless you prefix the method with $, which makes it accessible to the Alloy project and other widgets. For example, if the following code was defined in a widget controller:

```
$.init = function (args) {
    // Button object with id=button
    $.button.title = args.title || 'Si';
    $.button.color = args.color || 'black';
    // global variable
    message = args.message || 'Hola mundo';
}
```

Then, in the Alloy project, call init prefixed with the widget ID specified in the Alloy project's view--in this example, the ID is foo:

```
$.foo.init({title:'Yes', color:'gray', message:'I pity the foo.'});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $.hide = hide;
> ```

`$` reads the value of the variable named `$`.

`.hide` (assuming that value is an object, as it would be an error otherwise) accesses a property called `hide`.

`= hide` takes the value of the local `hide` variable (which is the function of the same name, *hoisted* because it was created using a *function declaration*) and assigns it to that property.

The next line works in the same way, just on differently named things.

> What I do not understand is how those two lines are making hide and show function accessible.

Either:

- The object that is the value of the `$` variable in the first bit of code is the same object that is the value of `$.loadIndicator` later.
- Some other code has copied those functions again

> And what can be possible equivalent code of those two lines.

Why do you need different code which does the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for Syntactical explanation, but what i did not understand is how setting properties to $ gives access to hide function in other controller. What is $ referring to here? - In terms of Titanium Appcelerator